# Meaning of the phrase 「さわいどるんかの？」

Tags: words, meaning, dialects, contractions

Here is the full sentence.

> いったいなにを**さわいどるんかの**？

What does the bolded part mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's [一体]{いったい}[何]{なに}を[騒]{さわ}いでいるんだ？ or 騒いでいるんですか？ "What's the fuss about?" in some regional dialect or the role language for old speakers.

Comment: To add, what is happening here is that おる is basically a dialectal form of いる, so we have さわいでおる, and then the でお contracts to ど, giving さわいどる.