# Ending a sentence with かの

Tags: meaning, particles

I recently came upon the following sentence (for a character thinking to themselves):

> ここは和にまかせるかの

What I assume is the loose translation "I think I will leave this to Nodoka"

The かの confuses me though. I can't find anything via Google about this particle combination. My only guess is that this could be some dialectical version of かな related to なあ->のう, since the speaker does speak with a distinctly western dialect.

Comment: Related (or duplicate?) https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23691/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23708/9831  Regarding the の: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12106/9831 /  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27433/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/80701/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72958/9831

Comment: Ah, so it is かねえ then?

Comment: Yeah, it's like ～かね(え)、～かな(あ)